# Is the affine cone of the Grassmannian a normal variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, grassmannian

Let $Gr(k,n)$ denote the complex Grassmannian embedded into $\mathbb{P} \Lambda^k \mathbb{C}^n $ via the Plücker embedding.

Using the fact that $Gr(k,n)$ is the union of open subsets isomorph to $ \mathbb{A}^{k(n-k)}$ (non zero loci of the plückercoordinates) one can see that the Grassmannian is normal.

As the title suggests, i am wondering if the same is true for the affine cone $X := X(k,n)$ of the Grassmannian. If i am not mistaken $X \setminus \{0\}$ is the union of open subsets isomorph to $\mathbb{C}^* \times \mathbb{A}^{k(n-k)} $, the latter beeing smooth.
Again, if i am not mistaken this suffices to conclude that the local rings $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ ,where $p \in X \setminus \{0\}$, are normal.

This would leave $\mathcal{O}_{X,0}$ to be inspected. Here are my thoughts so far:

$\mathcal{O}_{X,0} \cong K[X]_{m_0} =: R$ viewed as a subring of $K(X)$ is the set $\{ \frac{p}{q} \mid p,q \in K[X],q(0) \neq 0 \} $. Now let $a = \frac{p}{q} \in K(X)$ be the root of a monic polynomial over $R$, lets say
$$ a^n + \frac{p_{n-1}}{q_{n-1}}a^{n-1} + \cdots + \frac{p_1}{q_1}a + \frac{p_0}{q_0} = 0 $$ then we need to show $q(0) \neq 0. $
Defining $p_n = q_n = 1$ the above can be rewritten as
$$ \left( \sum_{i=0}^n p_i p^i q^{n-i} \prod_{j \neq i} q_j \right) \big/ \left( q^n \prod_{i=0}^nq_i \right)= 0 $$ hence
$ \sum_{i=0}^n p_i p^i q^{n-i} \prod_{j \neq i} q_j = 0$. If we now assume $q(0) = 0$ then $p(0)= 0$ follows, since $q_i(0) \neq 0$ for all $i$.

This is where i am stuck. Maybe there is a better approach ? Or is the statement in question just wrong ?

Comment: Are you using the Plucker embedding? The affine cone depends on the embedding: for instance, the cone over ${\mathbb P}^1$ viewed as a subset of itself is ${\mathbb A}^2$, while the affine cone over ${\mathbb P}^1 \simeq \{ X^2+Y^2+Z^2 = 0\} \subset {\mathbb P}^2$ is $\{x^2+y^2+z^2=0\}$ in ${\mathbb A}^3$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes i am indeed using the Plücker embedding. So the affine cone should be the set of decomposable $k$-forms in $\Lambda^k \mathbb{C}^n$ right ?